# Refactoring very similar JDBC prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to write some basic CRUD operations using JDBC. I'm wondering if there is a way I can use the same prepared statements for multiple tables. Right now, I have a function for every table, and it seems redundant, but I'm unsure how I can make it better.

Some code examples:

```
public static int insertIntoPeopleFilms(People people) {
    int newTableRow = -1;
    int peopleid = people.getPeopleid();
    for (URL filmUrl : people.getFilms()) {
        int filmsid = extractIdFromUrl(filmUrl);
        try (Connection conn = createDbConnection()) {
            newTableRow = getInsertIntoPeopleFilmsPreparedStatement(peopleid, filmsid, conn).executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    return newTableRow;
}

public static int insertIntoPeopleSpecies(People people) {
    int newTableRow = -1;
    int peopleid = people.getPeopleid();
    for (URL speciesUrl : people.getSpecies()) {
        int speciesid = extractIdFromUrl(speciesUrl);
        try (Connection conn = createDbConnection()) {
            newTableRow = getInsertIntoPeopleSpeciesPreparedStatement(peopleid, speciesid, conn).executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    return newTableRow;
}

private static PreparedStatement getInsertIntoPeopleFilmsPreparedStatement(int peopleid, int filmsid, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO people_films(peopleid, filmsid) VALUES (?,?)");
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, peopleid);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, filmsid);
    return preparedStatement;
}

private static PreparedStatement getInsertIntoPeopleSpeciesPreparedStatement(int peopleid, int speciesid, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO people_species(peopleid, speciesid) VALUES (?,?)");
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, peopleid);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, speciesid);
    return preparedStatement;
}
```

I essentially have this same code repeated for every table, with the only real difference being the names of the tables. Any advice on reducing the amount of code needed? Am I able to use a table name variable or something similar?

Comment: Just leave them as duplicate. SQL doesn't consider table name and fields to be a variable its messy to do so. You should be fetching the prepared statements before the loop and re-using them in the loop.

Comment: There wouldn't be any benefit anyway. These aren't complex queries that need extensive optimization. Just vanilla INSERTS.

Comment: You could reduce part of the code duplication by refactoring things, however, if something changes for one table, but not the other, it would be painful to undo that again. Choose carefully. Also although things are structurally the same, they are not logically the same, which is another reason to retain the duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a single prepared statement that inserts into different tables depending on some parameter.

Identifiers (for instance, table names) must be fixed at the time you prepare the statement. During the prepare, the SQL engine checks your syntax and also checks that the table exists. Once that validation is done, you can use the prepared statement freely and those checks don't need to be done as you execute. If you could change the table name per execution, then the SQL engine would need to re-check every time, which would partially defeat the purpose of preparing the statement.

Once the statement has been prepared, you can only change values. In other words, parameters can be used in place where you would have used a quoted string literal or a numeric literal, but no other part of the query.